# Reclaiming space used by deleted partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, disk-format

A few days ago I installed Mac OS and Linux Mint on my 2015 MacBook pro. I created a 412GB APFS container for mac and used the other 100GB for Linux. After wrestling with the issue, I learned that Apple blocks access to the Intel iGPU to third-party operating systems and Linux only uses the AMD GPU. I tried to delete the Linux partition using disk utility, but it did not see the Linux partitions, so I used a live CD to delete them. I am trying to reclaim that space to use on my Mac OS partition but it does not seem to be an option. Can I get help? I attached 3 pictures of what disk utility looks like for me.[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Terminal application command is given below. You can enter this command while booted to macOS.

```
sudo  diskutil  apfs  resizeContainer  disk0s2  0
```

This command has been known to fail if there is something wrong with your macOS APFS partition. Backing up important data is always a good idea.

The current version of the Disk Utility application assumes there will never be free space on a drive. When the Disk Utility removes a partition, the utility also returns the free space to another partition. Often, when one tries to do this with the `diskutil` command, two separate commands must be entered. The first command creates the free space and the second command adds the free space to a partition. You preformed the first part using live CD. The second command was given as my answer.

Comment: It worked! Can you provide an explanation of what this command did?

Comment: @Omar Kandiel: I updated my answer.